# Login to web services

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, authentication, web

I am currently stuck on the part where user use his username and password to view his data. I did try every piece of information on this website to find out how to make it work with no luck so far if anyone can point me in the right direction I'll be grateful.

here is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>




@interface ePaymentLoginViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UITextField *__weak usernameField;
IBOutlet UITextField *__weak passwordField;
IBOutlet UIButton *__weak loginButton;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *__weak loginIndicator;


}

@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *usernameField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UITextField *passwordField;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIButton *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *loginIndicator;


- (IBAction) login: (id) sender;


- (IBAction)backButton:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender;






@end
```

here is my .m file:

```
#import "ePaymentLoginViewController.h"

@interface ePaymentLoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation ePaymentLoginViewController

@synthesize usernameField;
@synthesize passwordField;
@synthesize loginButton;
@synthesize loginIndicator;





- (IBAction) login: (id) sender
{
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/%@/%@";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];

NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"text/json"]){

    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congrats" message:@"You are authorized" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertsuccess show];

} else {

    UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed" message:@"Username or Password Incorrect" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [alertsuccess show];

    loginIndicator.hidden = TRUE;
    loginButton.enabled = TRUE;

 [loginIndicator startAnimating];


}

}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
// Releases the view if it doesn’t have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren’t in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}




-(IBAction)backButton:(id)sender{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
-(IBAction)cancelButton:(id)sender{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}



@end
```

after successful login  this is how the url should look and it will send JSON data

```
http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/user123/test123    

{
   "Table": [
     {
       "comp_filenum": 1006842,
      "comp_namar": "username123",
      "comp_civid": "100000"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "tran_num": 30301,
      "inst_val": 1725,
      "balance": 3450,
      "late_amount": 3450,
      "late_inst_no": 2,
      "legal_status": 0,
      "baloon_balance": 0,
      "late_bal_no": 0,
      "remain_bal_no": 0,
      "clienttype": 2,
      "filenumber": 1006842,
      "customername": "username123",
      "civilid": "100000",
      "saleprice": 82800,
      "costprice": 66005,
      "last_receiptnumber": "e22512",
      "last_paydate": "2012-05-02T00:00:00",
      "last_payamount": 1725,
      "paidamount": 79350,
      "remaininginstallment": 16
    },
```

So what am i doing wrong at this point and what is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below line :

```
NSString *hostStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/%@/%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text]; 
NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString: hostStr]; 
NSLog(@"%@",aURL); // check the log 

NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL];
```

Comment: thanks thats one step closer that url had the wrong format, still dont know how to get it to verify it suppose to fetch json data from the server if the username and password is correct is their a way or part that im missing

Comment: its (http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/) without the (%@/%@) that was meant to be the input

Comment: u don't need user name and pass ?

Comment: sure i do but even when i got that part right  i dont get right message it always give me that username and password are wrong can you please tell me if im doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to show the value of **hostStr**

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",usernameField.text, passwordField.text];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/%@/%@";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
```

It will show :
`http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/%@/%@username/password`

Try with this :

```
NSString *hostStr = @"http://ourserver/mobilepay/MobilePayService.svc/verify/%@/%@";

NSString *url = [NSString  stringWithFormat:hostStr,usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
```

Comment: your right that did happen, although I'm still in that part trying to figure out why it wont load the data into the log area

Comment: it was a newbie mistake sorry btw